# kernel patch for touchpad

Tags: kernel, touchpad

I think this kernel patch can fix alps touch-pad can anyone help me to apply it on my system ?

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2326461/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the page on the link you gave there is the option to download the patch. Do this then follow the steps found here:  http://www.linuxheadquarters.com/howto/tuning/kernelpatch.shtml (basically extract into the /usr/src/linux [where the kernel source lives if you have it - the link explains how to get it if you haven't then use the patch command `patch -p1 < patchname`] then configure and replace existing kernel)  **Back Up BEFORE you try to do have a new (patched) kernel**  edit:  this is the address.    https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2326461/raw/

Comment: but the download is a text file ?

Comment: That's OK. Skip extracting and just go on to patch.

Comment: those lines are inside the file does it effect any thing ?
From patchwork Sun Mar 24 08:01:28 2013
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: [1/1] Feature: Support ALPS v6.
From: Valyushkov Ivan <ktopisal@gmail.com>

Comment: Did you click on the patch link? Because when I try it doesn't have that part.

Comment: i did, can you write the link you downloaded it from ?

Comment: oh i have clicked in mbox, i have done that:
cd /usr/src
patch -p1 < 1-1-Feature-Support-ALPS-v6..patch
and its saying
File to patch:
What do i have to do ?
Image:http://postimg.org/image/5fp1avqkd/

Comment: You need to be in the /usr/src/linux folder where your kernel source is stored. The problem was it could not find a file with the same name as the file it is meant to change.

Comment: update:http://postimg.org/image/h4pybzfcd/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9548/discussion-between-namingfailed-and-bahaa-zahika)

Comment: You'll need 20 reputation to talk here, Do you have skype ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9549/discussion-between-theliteyes-and-namingfailed)

Comment: Sorry no but my email is on profile. You can send to that.

Comment: i can't find your email on your profile can you write it ? and the chat is working for me now, my wireless internet connection is so slow at Ubuntu i don't why..

Comment: namingfailed at gmail.com

Comment: i have sent a message do you received it ?